# MYSQL Timestamp Issue

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I have a table called "users" and in that table there is a row for each account. In each row there is a column called "created" and in this I need to add the timestamp for when the account was created? So like when the user registers, the timestamp is automatically added. Also, when the values are updated in the row, I want the timestamp to stay the SAME. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the table, and apply the default value for your created column.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Users` (
  `User_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
... all other columns ...
  `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
)
```

There is no need to update the Created (timestamp) when user update the info.

Just update the columns that need a change (e.g. email, address, etc)

> using a trigger for the Created column is a bit overkill, I would say. It is better to use the default value instead. A Trigger in my opinion would be better for example a LastUpdated column. i.e. each time a user/account is modified it will update this column.